# Apparent loss of type information when mapping over a list

Tags: scala, types

I'm trying to declare a case class that takes two type parameters: a concrete type `A` and a type constructor `D`, constrained to be a subclass of a known one. My case class would then contain a `List[D[A]]`.

The problem I'm encountering is that, whenever I map on that list, I seem to lose the information of the type contained by `D`.

Here's what I have:

```
// Represents a named collection of documents of type A
trait Documents[A] {
  def name: String
  def take(target: Int): Documents[A]

  // [...]
}

// Represents a collection of named collections of documents.
// A is the type of a document, D that of a named collection of documents
case class Data[A, D[_] <: Documents[_]](docs: List[D[A]]) {
  // Makes sure no D contains more than target documents
  def cap(target: Int): Data[A, Documents] = {
    Data(docs.map(_.take(target)))
  }

  // [...]
}
```

This fails to compile with the following confusing (to me) error message:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : List[Documents[_]]
[error]  required: List[Documents[A]]
[error]     Data(docs.map(_.take(target)))
[error]                  ^
```

I don't understand how applying a function `D[A] => Documents[A]` to a `D[A]` can yield a `Documents[_]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Documents[_]` is using an existential type, which means you are telling the compiler you don't care about the type that is contained within `D`. So even if you specify that `docs` is a  `List[D[A]]`, the compiler really only treats it as `List[D[_]]`. What you actually want is to use a free type parameter, and not a wild-card in the type constraint. i.e. `D[B] <: Documents[B]`

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait Documents[A] {
  def name: String
  def take(target: Int): Documents[A]
}

case class Data[A, D[B] <: Documents[B]](docs: List[D[A]]) {

  def cap(target: Int): Data[A, Documents] = {
    Data(docs.map(_.take(target)))
  }

}
```

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that, in `D[_] <: Documents[_]`, both `_` are treated as different types?